# Bind ListItemCollection as a DataSource of a DataGridView

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, client-object-model

I am using SharePoint Server 2013. I am trying to show a list data in a DataGridView in a windows forms application(client application). I obtained the ListItemCollection object related to the specific list. How can I map that object to the datasource of the DataGridView?

I can't find any specific way to obtain a DataTable object from the ListItemCollection object. Because the list I used to obtain data is selected by a drop down list. So there is no predetermined columns for a Datatable object. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get DataTable object via [SPList.GetDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getdatatable.aspx) or [SPListItemCollection.GetDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.getdatatable.aspx) methods.